# dividing results of two PL/SQL select statements

Tags: plsql, division

The results of my two PL/SQL select statements are integers 27 & 50, I want their division (27/50) 0.54 at output...how to do that?

I have tried
select * from
((select....)/(select ...))
but it does not work!!

Comment: I don't know PL/SQL, but try casting both operands to floats before doing the division.  It may be doing integer division, which will give you 0 as the result (is that what you're seeing?)

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT thefirst FROM singlerowtable) / 
  (SELECT theother FROM othersinglerow) AS result
```

You can also use `CAST(thefirst AS FLOAT)` if you want to ensure a `FLOAT` division, &c.

Answer (score 5):

In your FROM clause you can only join result sets together, you can't use other operators like that.

You can, however, use arithmetic operators in your SELECT clause, e.g. (as Alex has already said):

```
SELECT (SELECT thefirst ...)
       /
       (SELECT thesecond ...) AS result
FROM DUAL;
```

or, alternatively:

```
SELECT A.thefirst / B.thesecond AS result
FROM   (SELECT thefirst ...) A
      ,(SELECT thesecond ...) B;
```

The first approach will fail if the result sets do not have exactly one row each.

The second approach will work even if the result sets have more than one row - you may have to supply join criteria between A and B if you don't want a cartesian join between the two result sets.